# Highlight column key Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to highlight only one specific row key, in this case "B" with pandas.

```
    1  2  3  4  5
```

A

**B**

C

I found different examples on how to highlight the row, but because the values in the row are color coded based on a conditional function and I need it to keep the color coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Styler.applymap_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap_index.html):

```
f = lambda v: "font-weight:bold;" if v=='B' else "font-weight:normal;"
f = lambda v: "font-weight:bold; color:red" if v=='B' else "font-weight:normal;"
df.style.applymap_index(f, axis=0)
```